# React Native use navigation.navigate outside Stack.Navigator tag

Tags: react-native

i want to create navigation Bar at the bottom of my app with always display on Top of all screens and clicking elements can navigate to the sec screens.

(On this setup it displays but the back button and the others (navigation) in my nav component does not work)

is the Navigation Bar.

Nav Pic:  [Click to check how Nav Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6i8y.png)

I want this left white arrow to go the previous screen.

The problem is, i can't use Navigation.goBack() in  comp because it cant be used outside Stack.Navigator comp

How would i be able to back to the previous screen, and my nav bar will be displayed on all screens ?.

Thanks!

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";

import Starter from "./Components/starter";
import Nav from "./Components/nav";
import Comp1 from "./Components/przystanki";

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Starter">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Starter"
          component={Starter}
          options={{ headerShown: false, animation: "fade_from_bottom" }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Comp1"
          component={Comp1}
          options={{ headerShown: false, animation: "fade_from_bottom" }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>


---> this is my nav <Nav />

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Nav.js

```
export default function Nav({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={styles.navItems}>
        <FontAwesome

----> this is what is not working  onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}

          style={styles.navIcon}
          size={22}
          name="arrow-left"
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.navItems}>
        <FontAwesome style={styles.navIcon} size={22} name="bookmark" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mainNavItem}>
        <FontAwesome style={styles.navIcon} size={22} name="bus" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.navItems}>
        <FontAwesome style={styles.navIcon} size={22} name="gear" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.navItems}>
        <FontAwesome style={styles.navIcon} size={22} name="user" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I've used this

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
 const navigation = useNavigation();
 

and here u can use navigation.goBack() / navigate/ pop etc.
```